# Flutter Obscure Text in an Text Widget

Tags: flutter

I would like to know if it is possible to obscure my Text in a normal Text Widget in Flutter.
And when it is how do I do that? I know that it is possible in a `TextField` but I would also like to do it in a normal text Widget in Flutter.

Answer (score 13):

You can obscure the text by yourself.

```dart
Text(
  isObscure == true
    ? _text
    : '${_text.replaceAll(RegExp(r"."), "*")}'
),
```

Comment: or you could use `"*" * _text.length`. You can [multiply strings in dart](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/String/operator_multiply.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can obscure the text by yourself.

```dart
Text(
  isObscure == true
    ? _text
    : '${_text.replaceAll(RegExp(r"."), "⬮")}'
),
```